# R: Plotting replicates in a time series

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series

Prepare for a stupid question...

I have a large set of data that looks a bit like this..

```
structure(list(V1 = structure(c(4L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("1012", 
"225", "58", "602", "62", "818"), class = "factor"), V2 = structure(c(4L, 
3L, 6L, 5L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("1012", "249", "58", "603", "62", 
"824"), class = "factor"), V3 = structure(c(6L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 
3L), .Label = c("1014", "117", "290", "442", "831", "992"), class = "factor"), 
V4 = structure(c(6L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 4L), .Label = c("1033", 
"1055", "166", "377", "831", "992"), class = "factor"), V5 = structure(c(3L, 
4L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 5L), .Label = c("1033", "1067", "1575", "190", 
"378", "832"), class = "factor"), V6 = structure(c(3L, 4L, 
6L, 2L, 1L, 5L), .Label = c("1034", "1069", "1575", "221", 
"379", "833"), class = "factor"), V7 = structure(c(3L, 5L, 
6L, 2L, 1L, 4L), .Label = c("1063", "1092", "2351", "379", 
"406", "834"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("V1", "V2", 
"V3", "V4", "V5", "V6", "V7"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
6L))
```

Each row represents a single subject, and each value moving along the columns represents the time within a session (in seconds) that a rat pressed a lever. I'd like to use ggplot to make a figure similar to [this](http://www.neuroxidence.com/Example_Datasets/Raster_Pattern_Plot_C2_C3Significant_joint_spike_events_Window_ID602.jpg). However I cant seem to figure out how to plot a time series as ggplot seems to want a discrete, named x and y. I can think of labor intensive ways to get it to work, but I know I'm just missing something simple.

Comment: ggplot2 functions work with data in long format. You need to use reshape2::melt on this data to get into long format. It should then be a piece of cake. (And there should be many worked examples on SO.)

Comment: I'll look into it. Thanks! Still trying to wrap my head around the seemingly endless ways to format data in R to make it play well with various functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DWin provided the answer to this in a comment above. I thought I could expand on it a bit in case anyone stumbles on this with a similar lack of experience. My solution was to install the reshapeGUI package as a quick means to learn the structure of the arguments.

After loading the GUI I took the above data, made the row numbers into a new column called "Subjects" and ran the following

```
test.melt <- melt(data = test, id.vars=c('Subjects'),     
measure.vars=c('V1','V2','V3','V4','V5','V6','V7'))
```

which gave me a structure described below, which is easily plotted as a time series showing values for each replicate/subject...

```
structure(list(subject = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "1", "2", 
"3", "4", "5", "6", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "1", "2", "3", 
"4", "5", "6", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"), response = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L), .Label = c("V1", "V2", "V3", 
"V4", "V5", "V6", "V7"), class = "factor"), time = c("602", "58", 
"818", "62", "1012", "225", "603", "58", "824", "62", "1012", 
"249", "992", "117", "831", "442", "1014", "290", "992", "166", 
"831", "1055", "1033", "377", "1575", "190", "832", "1067", "1033", 
"378", "1575", "221", "833", "1069", "1034", "379", "2351", "406", 
"834", "1092", "1063", "379")), .Names = c("subject", "response", 
"time"), row.names = c(NA, -42L), class = "data.frame")
```

Thanks DWin.